# Create a dynamic function in python/pandas for repeated np.where statements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am creating code in which there is alot of repetition of the function `np.where`. There are about 200 fields which each require some sort of transformation using `np.where` (essentially case when/ if then statements).

I was hoping to clean up the code by writing a function instead of repeating the statements for each field. The problem is that some fields require just a basic `np.where` statement whereas others have nested `np.where` statements (up to 10) and given this I am not sure how to make a function dynamic enough to deal with it or if it is even worth attempting this.

Sample

```
Case 1-  Simple np.where
TABLE[‘A’]=np.where(TABLE.FIELD1=='N',TABLE.FIELD2,TABLE.FIELD3)


Case 2- Nested np.where
TABLE[‘B’]= np.where(TABLE.FIELD1=='N','ADBE',
                          np.where(TABLE.FIELD1=='A','ADB ',
                          np.where(TABLE.FIELD1=='D','CDB ',
                          np.where(TABLE.FIELD1=='W','ODB ',
                          np.where(TABLE.FIELD1=='T','TDB ',
                          np.where(TABLE.FIELD1=='I','ODI ',
                          np.where(TABLE.FIELD1=='S','GDB ',       
                          np.where(TABLE.FIELD1=='B','BVP ',
                          np.where(((TABLE.FIELD1=='G')&(TABLE.FIELD2[0:4]=='UXXX')),'EGIB',
                          np.where(TABLE.FIELD1=='G','GIB ', 'null'))))))))))
```

Comment: I mean one approach would be to make a list of tuples where the tuples are the arguments for np.where. Then you can iterate through the list and apply np.where() to the args. Although this will only really save you time if you have a way to programmatically generate the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the below not work instead? It may even be more efficient, as less Boolean arrays need to be calculated and applied.

```
d = {'N': 'ADBE', 'A': 'ADB', 'D': 'CDB', 'W': 'ODB',
     'T': 'TDB', 'I': 'ODI', 'S': 'GDB', 'B': 'BVP'}

TABLE['B'] = 'null'
TABLE.loc[(TABLE.FIELD1=='G') & (TABLE.FIELD2[0:4]=='UXXX'), 'B'] = 'EGIB'
TABLE.loc[TABLE.FIELD1.isin(d), 'B'] = TABLE.loc[TABLE.FIELD1.isin(d), 'B'].map(d)
```